# Create a measure to get number of rows where both cells are blank

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table that looks like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
|  | row |
| 3 |  |
|  |  |
| 3 | row |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  | row |
| 3 | row |

From the table provided the output result should be (3) for the (3) rows that have blanks in both columns. I am looking to get the count of the instance where both columns are blank across the same row. Is this possible via a measure?

Answer (score 0):

Count the rows of the table where you filter both columns to be blank.

```
COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( Table1, ISBLANK ( Table1[A] ) && ISBLANK ( Table1[B] ) ) )
```

OR

```
CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Table1 ), ISBLANK ( Table1[A] ), ISBLANK ( Table1[B] ) )
```

Comment: This returned a count of (1), not sure what it is missing in the evaluation